# Problem in downloading data using Download Handlers in ShinyApp

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, shiny-server, dt

My original data of mtcar gets downloaded using *Download Handlers in ShinyApp* whereas i want the the *modified data (using SelectInputs)* to be downloaded through Handlers.
I have attached my codes as well, please let me know whats wrong with them. Many thanks:)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(DT)

data_table <- mtcars

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

downloadButton('downLoadFilter',"Download the filtered data"),

selectInput(inputId = "cyl", 
          label = "cyl:",
          choices = c("All",
                      unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
          selected = "4", 
          multiple = TRUE),

selectInput(inputId = "vs", 
          label = "vs:",
          choices = c("All",
                      unique(as.character(data_table$vs))),
          selected = "1", 
          multiple = TRUE),

DT::dataTableOutput('ex1'))

server <- function(input, output) {

thedata <- reactive({
if(input$cyl != 'All'){
  return(data_table[data_table$cyl == input$cyl,])
}

else if(input$vs != 'All'){
  return(data_table[data_table$vs == input$vs,])
}

else{
  return(data_table)
}
})

output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                                              escape = FALSE, 
                                              options = list(pageLength = 
10, scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE),{
                                                thedata() # Call reactive 
thedata()
                                              }))


output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
},
content = function(path){
  write_csv(thedata(),path) # Call reactive thedata()
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: don't remove the code for original answer, others need your question in the future, add a second section if needed

Comment: I placed the code for your new question in comments of Vishesh Shrivastav
 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `thedata()` only inside your `renderDataTable`. You need to make it a reactive and then use it for being rendered as DataTable and being downloaded.
Change your server to:

```
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  thedata <- reactive({
    if(input$cyl != 'All'){
      return(data_table[data_table$cyl == input$cyl,])
    }
    else{
      return(data_table)
    }
  })

output$ex1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                                                  escape = FALSE, 
              options = list(pageLength = 10, scrollX='500px',autoWidth = TRUE),{
                                 thedata() # Call reactive thedata()
                               }))


output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(path){
      write_csv(thedata(),path) # Call reactive thedata()
    })}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I have updated the codes (at top section) as you suggested. However i'm facing a problem in filtering out **vs column** using **else if** statement. Can you please have a look? Many thanks

Comment: thedata <- reactive({ 
include_by_cyl = if(input$cyl != 'All') data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl else rep(T,nrow(data_table)); 
include_by_vs = if(input$cyl != 'All') data_table$vs %in% input$vs else rep(T,nrow(data_table));
return(data_table[include_by_cyl & include_by_vs,]) })

Comment: thanks mate, I tried running it, but it doesn't work when you put 'cyl=All" and then change 'vs' to any value in selectInput